# Cannot use 'STWithin' as it can't be found for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' (SQL Server V14)

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I am currently using the STIntersects method to spatially match a geographic point to a geographic area. I am working with Geography types here not Geometry.
Historic code from the place I work shows that STWithin was previously used to carry out this operation.

From my googling, it appears that STIntersects will return a match if the point lies in or on the boundary of an area but that STWithin will only return true if the point is inside the area.

I want to try both methods, look at the results and fully understand exactly how they affect what we are trying to do with the data.

My problem is that when I try to use STWithin, e.g.

```
SELECT SourcePoint.STIntersects(TargetArea) FROM Table1

SELECT SourcePoint.STWithin(TargetArea) FROM Table1
```

...the STIntersect query works but the STWithin query gives:

**Could not find method 'STWithin' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'.**

I am using SQL Server V14 (2017) on a remote server. I've tried using a local SQL V15 server and I get the same result.

The Microsoft documentation seems to suggest it is available for SQL Server 2017:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stwithin-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your exact version number for SQL? I've tested this on SQL 2017 (14.0.3356.20) and SQL 2019 (15.0.2000.5) and it works fine using the code supplied in the documentation link. Also, SSMS is 15.0.18330.0, not that it should matter.

Comment: I'm on SQL Server 14.0.1000.169, SSMS 15.0.18369.0
The SQL in the document link doesn't work for me....weird.

Comment: So your version # is the RTM version, for lots of reasons you should patch this to the latest CU for SQL 2017, but you may find that patching fixes this issue as well.